# CSS label for tabs affects outer label

Tags: css

http://jsfiddle.net/oL49dz3p/3/

```
<label>Stuff for Tab One</label>
```

In the above example, tabs label has some style. And I want another generic label within the tab content but with a different style. But the generic label gets the same style as the tab label. How to escape the style from that

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the label a class or an id name like `<label class="InnerLabel">Stuff for Tab One</label>`

Then overwrite the undesired css you are getting from .tab, .tabs or .content using the .InnerLabel the class name.

```
.InnerLabel{
 position:static;
 margin:0;
 color:red;
}
```

The label will take on the properties of the InnerLabel class and overwrite any properties from your tabs class. So to "undo" any css from the tabs, tab, content or any other class, just overwrite the undesired properties and change them to whatever you'd like.

Comment: But still it inherits all the attributes from .tabs label. http://jsfiddle.net/oL49dz3p/3/

Comment: Do I need to reset all the attributes in .InnerLabel class that are set by .tab label. Is that the only way?

Comment: Since everything is contained in the div with class "tabs", you will need to overwrite all css attributes declared class tabs in your stylesheet. Your labels are also in the div with class "tab" so you will need to overwrite all css properties declared for the tab class as well.